# Create random pattern gradient maps?

Tags: python, numpy, gradient, procedural-generation, perlin-noise

So I have been working on some procedural generating and i managed to create a circular monochrome gradient map which i use to generate other maps.

```
def create_circular_gradient(self, world):
    center_x, center_y = self.mapSize[1] // 2, self.mapSize[0] // 2
    circle_grad = np.zeros_like(world)

    for y in range(world.shape[0]):
        for x in range(world.shape[1]):
            distx = abs(x - center_x)
            disty = abs(y - center_y)
            dist = math.sqrt(distx * distx + disty * disty)
            circle_grad[y][x] = dist

    # get it between -1 and 1
    max_grad = np.max(circle_grad)
    circle_grad = circle_grad / max_grad
    circle_grad -= 0.5
    circle_grad *= 2.0
    circle_grad = -circle_grad

    # shrink gradient
    for y in range(world.shape[0]):
        for x in range(world.shape[1]):
            if circle_grad[y][x] > 0:
                circle_grad[y][x] *= 20

    # get it between 0 and 1
    max_grad = np.max(circle_grad)
    circle_grad = circle_grad / max_grad
    grad_world = self.apply_gradient_noise(world, circle_grad)
    return grad_world
```

Now my question is, how exactly would i need to modify this to create a swirly gradient in a random way? and even maybe a box or a diverse linear gradients?

Note that `world` is a randomly generated 2d array (and can be any shape like 100x100 or even 100x50 but of course i use it a whole lot bigger) and to the circle gradient, I add a perlin noise to randomize the generation. The code that randomizes it will work for any map but i'm not sure where to start creating different shapes of gradient.

**Edit**
Ignore the magic numbers, that was the only way i found how to create a circular monochrome gradient

Comment: Your question is way too vague, what exactly is a "swirly gradient" anyway? Besides that, "random pattern" sounds like an oxymoron. There's also quite a few magic numbers in your code. I think the first thing you should do is define the input and desired outputs in fairly precise terms. Hmmm, maybe that's what you're asking how to do...

Comment: similar to this but no color is needed https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYHku.png

Comment: your `shrink gradient` block can be rewritten `circle_grad[circle_grad > 0] *= 20`. It's faster (no loop) and more readable for people used to numpy

Comment: I think your question boils down to how to create a gradient map that has an arbitrary shape or shapes in it. One way to do that would be to "render" the shape(s) onto the gradient map. There are a number of well-know ways of doing that including "scanline-conversion" of 2D polygons. The way to do it depends on how these "shapes" are defined. For example, another way to create them would be to apply a user-supplied function to every `[y][x]` position in it (which would handle what your current code is doing).